# Django filter limit objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

sorry for the stupid question.

I don't know where to find this solution or any keyword reference for it.

Let say, I have 2 models Place and Tips, and:

```
# list of place id
place_id_list = [...]
```

How do I filter tips over the place_id_list that just retrieve <= 5 tips object for every place

Here is the model:

```
class Place:
   ...
class Tip:
  # object_id is id of place
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False)
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
```

Right now, I just use **for loop** like:

```
tip_list = []    
for place_id in place_id_list:
    tip_list += Tip.objects.filter(object_id=place_id, content_type...)[0:5]
```

But this query seem to slow.

Is there any better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tip_list = []    
for place_id in place_id_list:
    tip_list += Tip.objects.filter(object_id=place_id, content_type...)[:5]
```

there is no better way than this, as you know django is lazy loader and doesnt hit the database unless a new object is needed,

Answer (score 1):

Try with below query:

```
tip_list =Tip.objects.filter(object_id__in=place_id_list, content_type...)[:5]
```

Reference link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut

Comment: No, it just return first five tips in all, I want to retrieve 5 tips with every place then push them into **tip_list**

Comment: Ohh, then you have to iterate though place_id_list, that's only the solution :)

Comment: the solution i've showed in question is the same :)